# Hiding client_secrets.json file from PyDrive (python3)

Tags: python, pydrive

I'm trying to create a python program that accesses the Google Drive API using PyDrive. However, one quirk of PyDrive is that it need a client_secrets.json file for OAuth2. Is there any way for me to hide the file so that the user is not able to see/access it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.